# App Crashes But Method Still Works?

Tags: java, android, exception, android-asynctask, runtime-error

I am trying to delete an item in my listview but keep getting an ArrayOutOfBoundException yet my LOG shows successful deletion from my Localhost and if you open it back it reflects the changes...

Not to sure how to fix the Exception that causes my app to crash? Any Ideas?

Class with Async Tasks:

```
  @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_view_all_locations);
        // Hashmap for ListView
        profileList = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();

        deleteLocation = (Button) findViewById(R.id.deleteLocation);
        locationCount = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.locationCount);
        lo = (ListView) findViewById(android.R.id.list);

        //setup adapter first //now no items, after getting items (LoadAllLocations) will update it
        adapter = new SimpleAdapter(
                ViewAllLocations.this, profileList,
                R.layout.locationitem, new String[]{TAG_ID,
                TAG_LATITUDE, TAG_LONGITUDE},
                new int[]{R.id.id, R.id.latitude, R.id.longitude});

        // updating listview
        setListAdapter(adapter);

        // Loading products in Background Thread
        new LoadAllLocation().execute();

        // getting product details from intent
        Intent i = getIntent();

        // getting product id (pid) from intent
        id = i.getStringExtra(TAG_ID);

        // Get listview
        ListView lo = getListView();

        lo.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                new DeleteLocation(position).execute();
                Map<String, String> item = profileList.get(position);
                String selectedItemId = item.get(TAG_ID);
                new DeleteLocation(position).execute(selectedItemId);

            }
        });

    }

    /**
     * **************************************************************
     * Background Async Task to Delete Product
     */
    class DeleteLocation extends AsyncTask<String, String, Integer> {

        int deleteItemPosition;

        public DeleteLocation(int position) {
// TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
            this.deleteItemPosition = position;
        }

        /**
         * Before starting background thread Show Progress Dialog
         */
        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();
            //pDialog = new ProgressDialog(ViewAllLocations.this);
            //pDialog.setMessage("Deleting Location...");
            //pDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
            //pDialog.setCancelable(true);
//            pDialog.show();
        }

        /**
         * Deleting product
         */
        protected Integer doInBackground(String... args) {

            String selectedId = args[0];

            // Check for success tag
            int success = 0; //0=failed 1=success
            try {
                // Building Parameters
                List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
                params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("id", selectedId));

                // getting product details by making HTTP request
                JSONObject json = jsonParser.makeHttpRequest(
                        url_delete_profile, "POST", params);

                // check your log for json response
                Log.d("Delete Product", json.toString());

                // json success tag
                success = json.getInt(TAG_SUCCESS);
                //if (success == 1) {
                // product successfully deleted
                // notify previous activity by sending code 100
                // Intent i = getIntent();
                // send result code 100 to notify about product deletion
                //setResult(100, i);

                //you cant update UI on worker thread, it must be done on UI thread
                // Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Location Deleted",
                // Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                //finish();
                // }
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            return success;
        }


        /**
         * After completing background task Dismiss the progress dialog
         * *
         */
        protected void onPostExecute(Integer result) {
            // dismiss the dialog once product deleted

            if (result == 1) {
                    //success
                   //delete from list and update listview
                profileList.remove(deleteItemPosition);
                adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                //pDialog.dismiss();
            } else {
            //failed
            }

        }

    }

    /**
     * Background Async Task to Load all product by making HTTP Request
     */
    class LoadAllLocation extends AsyncTask<String, String, Integer> {
        int success;

        /**
         * Before starting background thread Show Progress Dialog
         */
        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();
            pDialog = new ProgressDialog(ViewAllLocations.this);
            pDialog.setMessage("Loading Locations. Please wait...");
            pDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
            pDialog.setCancelable(false);
            pDialog.show();
        }

        /**
         * getting All products from url
         */
        protected Integer doInBackground(String... args) {
            // Building Parameters
            List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
            // getting JSON string from URL
            JSONObject json = jsonParser.makeHttpRequest(url_all_profile, "GET", params);

            // Check your log cat for JSON reponse
            Log.d("All Profiles: ", json.toString());

            try {
                // Checking for SUCCESS TAG
                success = json.getInt(TAG_SUCCESS);

                if (success == 1) {
                     // products found
                    // Getting Array of Products
                    userprofile = json.getJSONArray(TAG_LOCATION);

                    // looping through All Products
                    for (int i = 0; i < userprofile.length(); i++) {
                        JSONObject c = userprofile.getJSONObject(i);

                        // Storing each json item in variable
                        String id = c.getString(TAG_ID);
                        String latitude = c.getString(TAG_LATITUDE);
                        String longitude = c.getString(TAG_LONGITUDE);


                        // creating new HashMap
                        HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();

                        // adding each child node to HashMap key => value
                        map.put(TAG_ID, id);
                        map.put(TAG_LATITUDE, latitude);
                        map.put(TAG_LONGITUDE, longitude);


                        // adding HashList to ArrayList
                        profileList.add(map);
                    }
                } else {
                    // no products found
                    // Launch Add New product Activity
                    //Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),
                    // UserLocation.class);
                    // Closing all previous activities
                    // i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
                    // startActivity(i);
                }
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            return success;
        }

        /**
         * After completing background task Dismiss the progress dialog
         * *
         */
        protected void onPostExecute(Integer result) {
            // dismiss the dialog after getting all products
            pDialog.dismiss();
            locationCount.setText("" + profileList.size());
            if (result == 1) {
            //success
            //update adapter items
                adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            } else {
            //failed
            //launch activity here
            }


        }

    }
```

LOG: Delete Successful but still an error?

```
04-25 20:08:32.463  22736-23492/com.example.ankhit.saveme E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: AsyncTask #2
    java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occured while executing doInBackground()
            at android.os.AsyncTask$3.done(AsyncTask.java:299)
            at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.finishCompletion(FutureTask.java:352)
            at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.setException(FutureTask.java:219)
            at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:239)
            at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:230)
            at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1080)
            at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:573)
            at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:856)
     Caused by: java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: length=0; index=0
            at com.example.ankhit.saveme.ViewAllLocations$DeleteLocation.doInBackground(ViewAllLocations.java:144)
            at com.example.ankhit.saveme.ViewAllLocations$DeleteLocation.doInBackground(ViewAllLocations.java:117)
            at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:287)
            at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:234)
            at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:230)
            at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1080)
            at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:573)
            at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:856)
04-25 20:08:32.713  22736-22736/com.example.ankhit.saveme D/AbsListView﹕ unregisterIRListener() is called
04-25 20:08:32.733  22736-23498/com.example.ankhit.saveme D/Delete Product﹕ {"message":"Profile successfully deleted","success":1}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is originating from here

```
new DeleteLocation(position).execute();
Map<String, String> item = profileList.get(position);
String selectedItemId = item.get(TAG_ID);
new DeleteLocation(position).execute(selectedItemId);
```

You are running two separate tasks, but only the second task is given a parameter.  Therefore, the first task

```
new DeleteLocation(position).execute();
```

throws an exception, here

```
protected Integer doInBackground(String... args) {
    String selectedId = args[0];
    ...
}
```

`args[0]` is out-of-bounds because no args were passed to `execute`.

The second task is done in a different thread and manages to finish before the exception from the first task is passed back up the call stack, which is why it still "works".